# How can I not show a window until it is fully loaded with Pyside (Qt)

Tags: qt, pyside, python-2.x

users,

I want to build a preloader for a Qt-application created using Pyside. Since loading the main window takes some time because of loading data from a database and creating widgets dependent on that, I would like to have a frameless window which shows a progressbar and a logo before. I proceded to create this window.

Anyhow, if I start loading the main window then, things get messed up. Is there a way to check when the main window is fully loaded and not show it until then? Of course, I would then like to destroy the preloader window.

Any help appriciated.

Comment: See this special class QSplashScreen: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qsplashscreen.html

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I was searching for :)

Comment: Ok, in this case I posted this as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you to use `QSplashScreen`

http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qsplashscreen.html

As doc said:

> The QSplashScreen widget provides a splash screen that can be shown
>   during application startup.

As you can see with `QSplashScreen` you can set different images and set text tips to notify user.